# Upload FTP - PHP Barra de progresso

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmyadmin, ftp

Eu tenho um código pronto aqui, com upload para banco de dados e para uma pasta local que tem uma barra de progresso em javascript, porém o que eu queria era usar essa barra de progresso para fazer upload para uma pasta em um FTP e também para um banco de dados, mas não estou conseguindo alterar o código para que faça a conexão com o FTP. O que preciso alterar para que seja enviado para o FTP em vez do localhost. Segue o código abaixo:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Cadastrar Imagem</h1>
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
        }
        ?>
        <hr>
        <form action="#" class="form-horizontal"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titulo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="titulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o titulo">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagem</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" name="arquivo" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success upload">Cadastrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //Receber os dados
            $form = $(this);                
            var formdata = new FormData($form[0]);

            //Criar a conexao com o servidor
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //Progresso do Upload
            request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
            });

            //Upload completo limpar a barra de progresso
            request.addEventListener('load', function(e){
                $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('upload completo...');
                //Atualizar a página após o upload completo
                setTimeout("window.open(self.location, '_self');", 1000);
            });

            //Arquivo responsável em fazer o upload da imagem
            request.open('post', 'processa.php');
            request.send(formdata);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

processa.php:

```
include_once('conexao.php')

$tmp_name = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];


move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, '/public_html/softwares/'. $name);

$result_imagem = "INSERT INTO imagens (nome_imagem, titulo) VALUES ('$name', '$titulo')";
$resultado_imagem = mysqli_query($conn, $result_imagem);

if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Imagem cadastrada com sucesso!</div>";
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Erro ao cadastrar a imagem!</div>";
}
```

conexao.php

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "teste";

//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
```

Comment: Já tentou usar os exemplos da documentação? http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Comment: Então, eu tenho um outro arquivo em php que faz esse envio certinho, porém não estou conseguindo adaptar para funcionar junto com essa barra de progresso que mencionei acima. Esse arquivo usa essa função ftp-put.

Comment: Por padrão ftp_put não aceita callback, ou seja, não daria para pegar o progresso dele... talvez se criar outro arquivo com o ftp_nb_get, e vc fizer a consulta nele via ajax, ai vc consegue implementar a barra de progresso...

Resumindo, enquanto ele faz o upload, vc faz um "download" em paralelo e retorna pro browser, ai no browser vc faz o calculo da % do tamanho original com oq foi "upado/baixado"... Entendeu?

Comment: então do jeito que estou usando não tem jeito de colocar a barra de progresso né ? Essa função ftp_nb_get é muito complicada de usar ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-fget.php

tem os exemplos na documentação

Comment: pelo que pesquisei aq no google, não é tão trivial como um upload de formulário

Comment: só para entender direito, eu teria que usar o ftp_put para upar o arquivo e o ftp_nb_get para fazer o "download" das informações para a barra de progresso ?

Comment: sim, as soluções que vi eram nessa pegada...